# Action.async and using for-comprehention in a seperate function

Tags: scala, playframework

This might be even more Scala than Play related, but I have this issue within some Play code.

I have

```
def index = Action.async { implicit request =>
  val content1Future = Blogs.getAllBlogs(request)
  val sidebar1Future = Blogs.getAllBlogsOverview(request)

  for {
    sidebar1 <- sidebar1Future
    content1 <- content1Future

    sidebar1Body <- Pagelet.readBody(sidebar1)
    content1Body <- Pagelet.readBody(content1)
  } yield {
    val sidebarcontents = List(sidebar1Body)
    val contents = List(content1Body)
    Ok(views.html.main("Index", contents, sidebarcontents)).withHeaders(("Cache-Control", "no-cache"))
}
```

and it works fine.

Now, I try to extract the for-comprehention into a separate function dealing with 'sidebar' and I want to pass in the 'content'.

Like

```
def index = Action.async { implicit request =>
  standardMain(Blogs.getAllBlogs(request))
}

def standardMain(content1Future: => Future[Result])(implicit request: Request[_]) : Future[Result] = { 
val sidebar1Future = Blogs.getAllBlogsOverview(request)

for {
  sidebar1 <- sidebar1Future
  content1 <- content1Future

  sidebar1Body <- Pagelet.readBody(sidebar1)
  content1Body <- Pagelet.readBody(content1)
} yield {
  val sidebarcontents = List(sidebar1Body)
  val contents = List(content1Body)
  Ok(views.html.main("Index", contents, sidebarcontents)).withHeaders(("Cache-Control", "no-cache"))
}
```

}

But then I get

[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to D:\Dropbox\Playground\PlayWorld\play-with-forms\target\scala-2.11\classes...

[error] D:\Dropbox\Playground\PlayWorld\play-with-forms\app\controllers\Application.scala:91: type mismatch;

[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]

[error]  required: play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],?]

[error]       content1 <- content1Future

[error]                ^

[error] D:\Dropbox\Playground\PlayWorld\play-with-forms\app\controllers\Application.scala:90: type mismatch;

[error]  found   : play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],Nothing]

[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]

[error]       sidebar1 <- sidebar1Future

[error]                ^

[error] two errors found

[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed

[error] application -

I tried many different calls, but somehow I do not know how to get an play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],?].

How can I achive this. Thanks.

Comment: what type does `Blogs.getAllBlogs` return? Also, the errors you quote are not coming from the code you showed. Please fix your post, so that they match.

Comment: Please add signatures for getAllBlogs or getAllBlogsOverview, otherwise I would guess you need to change (content1Future: => Future[Result]) to (content1Future: Iteratee[Array[Byte], Nothing])